# How to avoid click going to outer web element located in same place in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate click on play button at https://onlineradiofm.in/stations/vividh-bharati
using selenium in python

Here is my code

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
url = "https://onlineradiofm.in/stations/vividh-bharati"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
play_button= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/pjsdiv[1]/pjsdiv[6]/pjsdiv[2]")))
play_button.click()
driver.quit()
```

The error I get is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <pjsdiv style="position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; pointer-events: none; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0s, transform 0.1s linear 0s; width: 20px; height: 20px; transform: scale(3); visibility: visible;">...</pjsdiv> is not clickable at point (214, 425). Other element would receive the click: <pjsdiv style="position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 0px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0s, background 0.1s linear 0s; cursor: pointer; transform: scale(3);"></pjsdiv>
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

My analysis is that the sibling web element covers my chosen web element . Hence this error appears.

Can you suggest a way to solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a really rough DOM! Would be nice to have anything useful to identify the elements.

Try this for the click - this works for me. It's a new xpath and a different wait condition.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
url = "https://onlineradiofm.in/stations/vividh-bharati"
driver.get(url)

play_button= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='oframeplayer']/pjsdiv[6]/pjsdiv/pjsdiv")))
play_button.click()
time.sleep(10) # This should play for this long - the browser may close after the script completes
```

Please note that the identifier `//*[@id='oframeplayer']/pjsdiv[6]/pjsdiv/pjsdiv` is still a poor identifier - but there is not much better to work with.

Comment: yes it works . I have noticed that you chose presence_of_element_located instead of element_to_be_clickable . Can you tell reason behind this ? Also how did you decide on [@id='oframeplayer']/pjsdiv[6]/pjsdiv/pjsdiv ? I chose xpath by watching what element changed when play button was clicked . None of that gives the xpath you chose. Thanks.

Comment: The player on the page seems to overlay a lot of objects. Not all are clickable as you've seen with your initial interception exception. Moving to it just being in the DOM is a sufficient check .see here for more info: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html

Comment: The new xpath - was a bit trial and error. There's no clear identifiers which suggest which element is the actual play button. If you picked yours based on what was changing, you might be identifying the lower/other svg elements as opposed the the controls  (noting that the paly icon > becomes pause || when you start the stream). My pattern was to pick what looked right, select it in the DOM, and trigger a click from the devtools console. If the click worked I had the right object. There's only a few elements in the cluster around the play icon so it didn't take long.